# This springboot ssl never works

Tags: spring-boot

I configured ssl on springboot correctly:

```
server.port=8443 
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:springboot.p12 
server.ssl.key-store-password=*****  
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
```

It always says the same whatever port I try:The Tomcat connector configured to listen on `port 8443` failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be mis-configured. Action:Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8443, or configure this application to listen on another port. Springboot will not start the application, it's so terrible as a framework with no way to debug it.
Any experienced developer could know such a bug that stuck me forever?!

Comment: It seems that something else is already running on port 8443. If you are on Linux or a Mac you can find that out using "lsof -i -P -n | grep 8443"

Comment: Nope. I checked windows. @NullishByte

Comment: On windows it works using `netstat -aof | findstr :8443` (source: [How can you find out which process is listening on a TCP or UDP port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows))

Comment: Already tried it so many times, it's something else. @DanielW.

Answer (score 1):

Its apache2 use it:

```
     SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /abc.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /abc.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /abc.ca-bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to use this way exactly to make it work:

https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ssl-https-examples/